# Show a Subspace of regular space is regular

Tags: general-topology, proof-explanation

[image]

I use this definition .Proofs of this theorem
I saw are  based on a similar def,  but with functions.
Source:
([https://www.math.tamu.edu/~tomzz/math636/ass7.pdf](https://www.math.tamu.edu/%7Etomzz/math636/ass7.pdf))

**Attempt**

Let (X$,\mathcal{T}$) be a regular topology.
Let $\mathcal{T}_S$={O$\cap$ S :O$\in\tau$}

Suppose X is a regular and $S\subseteq X$,S closed and any point  x$\in A$ and V$\subset A$

Let x$\in S\setminus A$, then $S\setminus A$ is open

Then there exists U open set in X s.t U $\cap S$ =V

Clearly $ x\notin$ U else x$\in V$

Since X is regular  (S$\setminus A )\cap S=\emptyset$

Comment: Your source is about * completely regular* spaces, a different property.

Comment: So l am proving it is T3 ?

Comment: $T_3$ for me (but textbooks differ in this!) includes $T_1$ so a separate proof or quoted result is needed for the fact that the subspace is also $T_1$.

Comment: Morris terms this theorem regular.

Comment: My proof below is for regular as Morris defined it. If you add the $T_1$ fact it will also be a proof that the subspace is $T_3$ too when $X$ is $T_3$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do the proof more systematically. Don’t needlessly  repeat definitions.

Let $(X,\tau)$ be a regular space and let $S \subseteq X$ be a subset in the subspace topology.

Let $x \in S$ and let $C \subseteq S$ be closed in $S$ such that $x \notin C$.

By standard facts about the subspace topology, there is a closed subset $C’$ of $X$ such that $$C = C’ \cap S$$

It’s clear that $x \notin C’$ as well, so by regularity of $X$ there are open sets $U$ and $V$ of $X$ such that $x \in U$, $C’ \subseteq V$ and $U \cap V = \emptyset$.

Then $U’ = U \cap S$ is open in $S$ and contains $x$, $V’=V \cap S$ is open in $S$ and $$C = C’ \cap S \subseteq V \cap S = V’$$

Of course $U’ \cap V’ \subseteq U \cap V = \emptyset$ so these sets show that $S$ is regular.

Comment: I thought x$\in S\setminus A$ Ok,but people ask what defs I use,so. I post em.

Comment: @Homer $x \in S\setminus A$ is the same as when I write $x \in S$ and $x \notin A$.

Comment: Since C=C’ $\cap$ S is closed and x$\notin C’$ can we say for U an V in X that U=X\C’ $\cap$ S ?

Comment: @Homer i use $C’$ is closed plus regularity of $X$ to get disjoint $U$ and $V$. I don’t see the point of your remark.

Comment: I thought it was complement. You

Comment: @Homer neither. Just $C$ prime.

Comment: Just a little observation if x$\in C’$ then X is not regular since no open sets U and V exist

Comment: @Homer $x$ cannot be in $C'$ because then it would be in $S \cap C' = C$ which it is not. So regularity of $X$ *can* be applied.

Comment: @Homer $x \notin C$ is given. $x \notin C'$ follows.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not following your proof.  You need to show that a subspace of X is regular.   You need to give it a name, if you are using $A$ that might confuse you with the $A$ in the theorem so I suggest calling it something else, like let $S\subseteq T$ be equipped with the subspace topology (IE a set is open in $S$ if and only if it is equal to the intersection of an open set $U$ in $T$ with $S$).

Now, within $S$ you need to show regularity, so you need to take a closed set in $S$, call it $A\subseteq S$ and a point  $x\in S\setminus A$  and show there exists open sets $U,V$ in the subspace topology that separate $A$ and $x$ in $S$.  Hint: Consider what it means to be closed set in $S$ compared to $T$,  then use the regularity of $T$ to generate $U',V'$ in $T$ that you can then derive your $U,V$ in S from.

Comment: Is this better @Alan